# How to display the multiple objects in slide using ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am new to ionic 2, I want to display the multiple products in single slide,I am able to display the slide but i am getting small dots below the image.How can i remove the dots.
Below is my html code:

```
<ion-row class="brandNameSlideSize">
<ion-slides pager [options]="mySlideOptionsCategory">
   <ion-slide *ngFor="let catName of brandName" 
   (click)="infoBrandItem(catName);">
       <img class="imageCat" src={{catName.image}}>
       <p>{{catName.name}}</p>
      </ion-slide>    
   </ion-slides>
  </ion-row>
```

Below is my ts file code:

```
mySlideOptionsCategory = {
slidesPerView: 4
 };
this.productServices.getBrandName(function(data){
 _this.logger.debug("checking procutName" +data);
 _this.brandName = data.data.categories;
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `pager="false"` in your `ion-slides` tag. This should solve it.

Comment: ;i try that one but only removing the dots not add single sild  multipul images

Comment: i try that one  dots are removed but not add multipul oimages in single slid